# JQuery ajax function sends the correct value.But RestController receives null

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-restcontroller

These codes are RestController of my spring boot project,

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/user")
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("login")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> authenticated(@RequestBody User user) {

        System.out.println(user.getUsername() +":"+ user.getPassword()); //This line returns NULL password value

        Boolean blogin = userService.authenticate(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        if(!blogin)
            return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(blogin, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);

        return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(blogin, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And Below codes are JQuery ajax java-script codes.

```
function ajax_login_submit() {

    var user = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val()
        }; 

    console.log(user);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "rest/user/login",
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            var resultJson = JSON.stringify(data);
            $('#helloUserDiv').html(resultJson);
            console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
            alert(data);

        },
        error: function (e) {

            var resultJson = e.responseText;
            $('#helloUserDiv').html(resultJson);
            console.log("ERROR : ", e);
        }
    });
}
```

`console.log(user);` of java script returns the correct value.

```
{"username":"joseph","password":"password"}
```

But in the RestController codes, password value is missing, "NULL". 
The line `System.out.println(user.getUsername() + ":" + user.getPassword());` returns strange value, `"joseph:null"`
Is it possible for JQuery ajax method not to transfer the json value to REST server? If I make some mistakes, kindly inform me how to send the json value to REST server correctly.

Comment: Note it is very easy to inspect what actually got sent by inspecting the full request in browser dev tools network tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "rest/user/login",
        data: JSON.stringify({"username": $("#username").val(), "password": $("#password").val()}),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            var resultJson = JSON.stringify(data);
            $('#helloUserDiv').html(resultJson);
            console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            var resultJson = e.responseText;
            $('#helloUserDiv').html(resultJson);
            console.log("ERROR : ", e);
        }
});
```